# How does a strict preference relation entail non-strict preference relation

Tags: relations

I am currently stuck on a problem for decision theory. I am not super good at proofs so I cannot progress very well. Does anyone have tips about how to deal with
this question?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS2on.jpg)

A clear and explanation or some guidance would be greatly appreciated. I am really interested in understand how to address this question but just don't feel I'm able to grasp at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: You just work through methodologically.  For example knowing $x \prec y$ or  $y \prec x$ or $x \sim y$, you know $x \prec y$ or $x \sim y$ or $y \prec x$ or $y \sim x$, and so $(x \prec y$ or $x \sim x)$ or $(y \prec x$ or $x \sim y)$ and thus $x \preccurlyeq y$ or $y \preccurlyeq x$

Comment: Thank you this helped heaps I understand now